# Lock out users after three unsuccessful attempts without using a database

Tags: asp.net

I want to lock out my users after three unsuccessfull attempts without using a database.

I was trying:

```
public int loginAttempts()
{
    if (!(ViewData["loginAttempts"] == null))
    {
        ViewData["loginAttempts"] = int.Parse(ViewData["loginAttempts"].ToString()) + 1;
        return int.Parse(ViewData["loginAttempts"].ToString());
    }          
    else
    {
        ViewData["loginAttempts"] = 1;
        return 1;
    }
}
```

But it always returns 1. What modifications do I need to make?

Comment: perhaps it resets the viewdata each time the page loads?

Comment: this in mind, i would use the database for it anyway. I'd have a "loginattempt" table to track all login attempts, and i would lock a user out if there are three or more unsuccessful login attempts in the last XYZ amount of time. This prevents a distributed brute force attack from a botnet. It also gives you insight into account sharing (if you track the IP of the attempt_

Answer (score 3):

You'd need to store this in the session, not view data.  View data is sent to the view and is not persisted between requests.

```
public int loginAttempts()
{
    if (!(Session["loginAttempts"] == null))
    {
        Session["loginAttempts"] = int.Parse(Session["loginAttempts"].ToString()) + 1;
        return int.Parse(Session["loginAttempts"].ToString());
    }          
    else
    {
        Session["loginAttempts"] = 1;
        return 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanku very much Mr. Tavnfosson.. Please tell me how to lock user.. As I am using MVC 1.0. and IslockOut property of MembershipUser is readonly..I want to lock user for certain time after 3 unsuccessful login attempts

Comment: @user - are you using the SqlMembershipProvider?  You set the maximum failed attempts in the configuration along with the failed attempt window.  The provider itself will lock the user out when the user has failed too many times within the window.  If you're implementing your own, you should do the same.  The AD provider uses the settings on the domain.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Session state](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178581.aspx) variables.